# Spring Cron Nth weekday

Tags: spring, cron

I was working on a project and I need to save cron expressions on either a weekly or monthly basis.  Monthly crons are created on a nth day of the week.  I am using [cron-utils](http://cron-utils.com/) to create the cron, and found on this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/cron-expressions) that Spring Cron supports an nth day of the week.  However as I have written the code, I have found little to no support for the nth day of the week using a hash.  I have searched the internet and have not found a definitive answer as to whether or not spring supports the nth day of the week.  So, does Spring Cron support the nth day of the week or not?

Before you answer to not add the tag, just think I want something to run "every 2nd Wednesday of each month".

Answer (score 0):

I just checked, and the feature is supported by [Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html), and [cron-utils](http://cron-utils.com/) as well. Below the appropriate code:

```java
import org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronExpression;
CronExpression.parse("0 0 0 ? * WED#2");
```

This would run the cron the second Wednesday in the month at midnight. A similar example is provided [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronExpression.html).

In cron-utils you can parse the same expression with the following code:

```java
import com.cronutils.model.CronType;
import com.cronutils.model.definition.CronDefinitionBuilder;

CronParser parser = new CronParser(
    CronDefinitionBuilder.instanceDefinitionFor(CronType.SPRING)
);
parser.parse("0 0 0 ? * WED#2");
```